# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

I have installed module-Ubercart,after installation,when I want to add a ne product content.The problem display like below:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'zhutaobcn.uc_countries' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {uc_countries} WHERE country_id = :id AND version > :version; Array ( [:id] => 840 [:version] => 0 ) in uc_store_default_country() (line 1694 of D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\drupal\modules\ubercart\uc_store\uc_store.module).
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

whats wrong with my Drupal?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you didn't run update.php after installing or upgrading modules?  Also worth posting in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/